# AWS Identity and Access Management uses REST or SOAP API

Tags: api, rest, soap, amazon-web-services

Is AWS Identity and Access Management uses REST or SOAP API?

They are saying the API as [**IAM API**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/Using_WaysToAccess.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS IAM can be accessed using either Rest or Soap. To authenticate to rest you use the AWS Access and Secret access keys, and for Soap you use the x509 credentials. You can find the x509 credentials in the management console for the root user.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Identity and Access Management uses REST API.